# rvest, table with thead and tbody tags

Tags: r, rvest

I am slowly learning webscraping using rvest. I would like to scrape the following table
https://novostavby.com/cs/developery/ 
I am mainly interested in the first column, but I don't mind obtaining the whole table.

I tried two possible ways. The simplest one that parsed the head only:

```
url <- 'https://novostavby.com/cs/developery/'
read_html(x=url) %>% 
  html_nodes('table') %>% 
  html_table
```

Next I tried

```
html_nodes(webpage, 'table') %>% html_nodes('.type')
```

but it returned the header only (do not know why...)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The rows of the table aside from the header get loaded dynamically from a server or other data source. Scraping the source like this will only get what's static in the page. You can try tools like selenium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your url points to an html page which contains an empty table. The reason why you can see the contents of the table in your web browser is that the html instructs your browser to download the table's contents from a different page and inserts it into the empty table. Of course, [rvest](/questions/tagged/rvest) just reads the first page's html without running the javascript to load the table data.

In your case, the data is loaded from another url which points to a JSON file. It is actually possible to insert its contents into the original html and use rvest to get your table. This is effectively doing manually what your browser does.

```
require(httr)
require(magrittr)
require(rvest)

# Get the page's html as text
url <- 'https://novostavby.com/cs/developery/'
original_page <- GET(url) %>% content("text") 

# Get the JSON as plain text from the link generated by Javascript on the page
json_url <- "https://novostavby.com/ajax-estatio-developers/?citypath=undefined&sortdir=asc&sortfield=title&search=&pagefrom=developers"
JSON <- GET(json_url) %>% content("text", encoding = "utf8") 

# Remove the double escapes and enclosing brackets / html key from the JSON
# to get its html contents
table_contents <- JSON     %>%
 {gsub("\\\\n", "\n", .)}  %>%
 {gsub("\\\\/", "/", .)}   %>%
 {gsub("\\\\\"", "\"", .)} %>%
  strsplit("html\":\"")    %>%
  unlist                   %>%
  extract(2)               %>%
  substr(1, nchar(.) -2)   %>% 
  paste0("</tbody>")

# insert the table html into the original page
new_page <- gsub("</tbody>", table_contents, original_page)

# Now you can read the table with rvest
read_html(new_page)   %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table()
```

This gives you the table you wanted. The only problem is that all the non-ascii characters appear as unicode such as u00de. You'll need to gsub these to their character equivalents.